Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS localhost tty1 does not recognize my user name. How can this be fixed?I
I have somehow shut down my Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS desktop. while attempting to correct a persistent problem of sound loss probably caused by pulseaudio and dependencies. No thanks to perplexity AI....
Right now I need help with dealing with this dark screen that comes up on reboot which states:
Ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS localhost tty1
localhost login:
I did not do the setup/installation for this desktop. I have attempted to use various user names but all have failed.
Any suggestions?
If I have to, I am open to wiping the hard drive and attempting to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS but fear that will present even more challenges...

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
